# How to get month name from date in Presto

Tags: function, date, monthcalendar, presto

I use Presto and I do not know the function to get MONTH's name from a date column. I can get MONTH number using `MONTH(<date>)` function but I'm not able to get MONTH name.

I've seen ways where a list of month names is manually created and the number is matched over with the list to obtain the name. Is there a better approach to use any known function in Presto?

Comment: Any reason why it's a -1 for the question? I guess I've given details in the question after doing research.

Comment: Please specify any code you have. From documentation, https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html, there is the `%M` specifier that should do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398999/how-to-get-month-name-from-date-in-presto#comment81751375_47398999), Presto provides [`date_format` function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) which is compatible with MySQL one. `%M` will tell you the exact month name of your timestamp. For example:

```
SELECT date_format(timestamp '2017-11-21 12:00:00', '%M') month_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Presto , you can also use following function: -

```
SELECT extract(MONTH from CURRENT_DATE) Month
```

And Output would look like:-

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the date_trunc function

SELECT date_trunc('month', date) as Month

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).